# Проверка на буквы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу проверить есть ли в строке только буквы. Запускаю цикл и в итоге выходит так что в цикле если введу букву, то все равно оно думает что буквы нет. Можете помочь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш пример обычным текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: так у вас в цикле нет проверки буква или нет, только ввод. бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 2):

а кто в цикле будет делать проверку на буквы?

у вас этого в коде нет, переменная `inputNameStr` не меняется и цикл не прерывается

ну и вообще то задача может обойтись и одним `input` под `while`, не стоит усложнять текст сверх необходимого

```
text = ""
while True:
    text = input()
    if text.isalpha():
        break
```

**P.S.**

кстати стандарт питон просит для булева типа использовать `is` и `is not` вместо `==` и `!=`

Comment: лучше не использовать `is`, `is not` и `==`, `!=`, правильней будет писать просто `value` и `not value`.